# Vim and assigning function to a key

Tags: vim, key-bindings, dvorak

### Hi!

For about 3 last weeks, I have been using Vim. I must say, I love the navigation keys on the home row!
A week ago I switched to Dvorak, and the new location of the movement keys, simply doesn't let me use Vim. It's terrble.
So, I wonder, is there a way to keep movement keys in Dvorak, in the same location as in qwerty?

I don't want to remap keys, as that would be super-confusing. One way I can think of is to assign the function i.e `go up one line` from key <kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>t</kbd>.

So I could have my movement keys in dvorak(<kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>) layed out as in qwerty (<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>)
Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to remap keys, as that would be super-confusing

You probably want to remap keys, but just in Vim. However the fine people over at vim.wikia.com [doesn't think this is such a good idea](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout#Comments).

One alternative, as mentioned in the linked article, is to use dvorak in insert mode, and qwerty-position of binds in normal mode, i.e. <kbd>w</kbd> = <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> = <kbd>c</kbd> etc.

> set
>   langmap='q,\,w,.e,pr,yt,fy,gu,ci,ro,lp,/[,=],aa,os,ed,uf,ig,dh,hj,tk,nl,s\;,-',\;z,qx,jc,kv,xb,bn,mm,w\,,v.,z/,[-,]=,\"Q,E,PR,YT,FY,GU,CI,RO,LP,?{,+},AA,OS,ED,UF,IG,DH,HJ,TK,NL,S:,_\",:Z,QX,JC,KV,XB,BN,MM,W<,V>,Z?

-

> One way I can think of is to assign the function i.e "go up one line" from key <kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>t</kbd>, so I could have my movement keys in dvorak(<kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>) layed out as in qwerty (<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>)
>   Is it possible? How can I do that?

Remember that doing such a thing could break other keys, I can't really tell as it's hard without actually trying/comparing each key. You could however remap all of those keys to custom positions if you'd want to using `nnoremap` etc.

A basic remapping would be just to remap the home row like this.

```
nnoremap d <Left>
nnoremap h <Down>
nnoremap t <Up>
nnoremap n <Right>
```

All in all I don't think it's such a good idea to combine two keyboard layouts, so just remapping home row is probably the safest, and then learn that <kbd>e</kbd> etc. has custom positions compared to qwerty.

These problems is why I never bothered to switch to Dvorak og Colemak, because I'd have to relearn all those binds that I have in my muscle memory, for a new vim user it might not be such a big issue though, so you're lucky that way!

Comment: Well, do you know how could i change the key's function? I'd like to at least try.

Comment: @ravik1222 "Changing the key's function" would be to `remap` it some way or another in vim. Remapping keys isn't dangerous unless it'll affect other binds, which in this case it will. I'm sorry, but I just don't think there's a good all-around "solution", it'd be up to personal preferences, so take a look at the `:h remap` docs and add whatever you do to `~/.vimrc` and see what fits you best.

Comment: @ravik1222 Sorry, you could of course use `<Left>` etc. (updated)! I'm getting a little confused as to what the result would be. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm ; ] . About unbound keys: I don't mind having strongly personalized vim - it's all about personalization, so I can as well find a good place to remap back dhtn keys.

Comment: @ravik1222 Good to hear! I'm getting all dizzy trying to compare the different keys in the different keyboard layouts, so whatever you'll do with any keys that (might) be weird is up to you :)

Comment: Well g q v K V # * \ = ^A ^C ^I ^K ^O ^V ^W ^X, these are all normally unbound keys and 'g' is a good substitute for 'd', and 'v' for 'n'. It's done - you saved my life sir! : }

Comment: @ravik1222 Ah, right. Good to hear that my answer was sufficient!